# How to paste values from array to a column in the spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, vba, csv, range

I have a 1-dimensional array of numbers.
I want to paste this into a new csv file.
But the problem is that only the first value of the array is pasted.

After I collect the numbers into the array and create a new CSV file, this is the code I'm trying to use to paste the array:

```
FSO.CreateTextFile ("C:\users\lloyd\Coding\vbafolder\missingclose.csv")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\users\lloyd\Coding\vbafolder\missingclose.csv")

Range("a1").Select

Range("a1:a" & arraycount).Select
Selection.Value = noCloseArray
```

How can I paste my entire array into each cell of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Every time an item is added into the array, the arraycount is increased by 1 If there's 100 items in the array, then arraycount is 100). So the array count is as big as the array

Comment: arraycount is 820. The first value is a date, and the remaining 819 values are strings (not numbers, which I mistakenly claimed)

Comment: Try `Range("A1:A" & arraycount).Value = Application.Transpose(noCloseArray)`.

Comment: 1D arrays in VBA are horizontal. If your ultimate goal is to write to a sheet, it's better to use a 2D array.